# Not allowed to load local resource: (Server side)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to load an image which is theorically on my local C but this folder links to a server.

I've already tried to type **file:///** or **file://///** before the path, but nothing seems to work.
I'm leaving you the website so you can see by yourself the error in the console and maybe explain to me why it does get stuck!

Website:

http://www.lnf.infn.it/user.html > Scientif Committee > Righ click on that gray background you see at first.

Follow these steps and you should get the errors

Comment: This really won't work. You're telling the client browser to look for a file in the client's computer. It's also a protocol mismatch, between HTTPS and FILE, which violates Same-Origin Request Policy.

You need to move the file to the server that's hosting the rest of the website. If you can't, put this file in another server, accessible via HTTP, and link from there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the image on server? Then it's easier, you just have to write the relative url without the "file://"

Comment: I totally agree with you. nfortunately this is not my website, it's of a company and they gave me this access

Comment: I can see with right click that you write:  url("file://///afs/lnf.infn.it/project/www/lnf/committee/nuovo_sito/images/acc.jpg"); ..try to remove some " // " and add C:/, for example: url("file://C:\Users\bg.jpg");

Answer (score 0):

"file://" method will work only if you are browsing webpage on the same computer where your website is hosted and running. You should either try a absolute URL (ex: http://..../file.ext ) or relative url (ex: "/images/myimage.png" ) to display an image.

Comment: So I should get the absolute URL right? Is there a way to get it with code?

Comment: @Jake — You are already using an absolute URL. It's just that file scheme URLs are blocked.

Comment: @Jake You may need to move those files under any web server, or publicly available path using http/https method.

Comment: Right guys, but anyway @Quentin you mean like https://afs.... ?

Comment: @Jake — No, I mean `file:`.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say: should I write https:// afs/lnf.... @Quentin

Comment: @Jake — Only if you host the image on that URL first.

Comment: I guess I'm gonna run a php script to find the rifght path @Quentin